# Ant Design: How to Switch light or dark theme in production?

Tags: antd

How do I dynamically switch between dark theme and light theme of Ant Design in a create-react-app production environment?

Answer (score 1):

app.jsx

```js
import { Button, Select } from 'antd';
import { ThemeProvider, useTheme } from 'antd-theme';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { SketchPicker } from 'react-color';

const initialTheme = {
  name: 'default',
  variables: { 'primary-color': '#00ff00' },
};

const ThemeSelect = () => {
  const [{ name, variables, themes }, setTheme] = useTheme();

  return (
    <>
      <Select
        style={{ width: 100 }}
        value={name}
        onChange={
          (theme) => setTheme({ name: theme, variables })
        }
      >
        {
          themes.map(
            ({ name }) => (
              <Select.Option key={name} value={name}>
                {name}
              </Select.Option>
            )
          )
        }
      </Select>
      <SketchPicker
        color={variables['primary-color']}
        onChange={(value) => {
          // Will update all css attributes affected by primary-color
          setTheme({ name, variables: { 'primary-color': value.hex } });
        }}
      />
    </>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const [theme, setTheme] = React.useState(initialTheme);
  return (
    <ThemeProvider
      theme={theme}
      onChange={(value) => setTheme(value)}
    >
      <ThemeSelect />
      <Button type="primary">Button</Button>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

config-overrides.js

```js
const { override, fixBabelImports, addLessLoader, addPostcssPlugins, adjustStyleLoaders, addWebpackPlugin } = require('customize-cra');

const AntdThemePlugin = require('antd-theme/plugin');

module.exports = override(
  fixBabelImports('import', {
    libraryName: 'antd',
    libraryDirectory: 'es',
    style: true,
  }),
  addLessLoader({
    javascriptEnabled: true,
  }),
  adjustStyleLoaders(
    (loaders) => {
      loaders.use[0] = {
        loader: AntdThemePlugin.loader
      }
    }
  ),
  addWebpackPlugin(
    new AntdThemePlugin({
      themes: [
        {
          name: 'dark',
          filename: require.resolve('antd/lib/style/themes/dark.less'),
        },
        {
          name: 'compact',
          filename: require.resolve('antd/lib/style/themes/compact.less'),
        },
      ],
    })
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that I've created today. This [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/antd-theme-vars) will help you. It just convert your theme settings to css vars and less vars (get of .less files)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32967916)